# SQL : Delete row only having 1 row count if it has more then 2 then not delete it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I need to delete records id tow table having match record only one. if both table have match records more then tow then not need to delete;

I try this but got error :

```
    DELETE FROM 
  tbl_team 
where 
  team_id = (
    SELECT 
      external_team_id 
    from 
      tbl_service_data 
    WHERE 
      id = '13481' 
      AND team_type_id = 2
  ) 
  AND 
HAVING 
  count(*) = 1
```

what I need it I just need to delete if and if only have one match record.

but this is give me error as below :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'HAVING count(*) = 1' at line 1

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you mean, but this query will delete from table 1 where the ID appears in table two only once:

```
DELETE FROM t1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM t2 GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

If there were these 4 records in T2:

```
1,
2,
2,
3,
```

Then this is what happens to these 3 records in T1:

```
1 --deleted
2 --not deleted: present in t2 twice
4 --not deleted: not present in t2
```

T2 having ID 3 once would mean ID 3 in T1 is specified for deletion, but because T1 doesn't contain ID 3, no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE From tbl1 where exists (
select id from tbl2  where   tbl2.id = '13481' 
  AND tbl2.team_type_id = 2 and tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
group by id having count(*) = 1 
)
```

forget the delete action , in this way it is like you are making an inner join on the same table than you are deleting those rows existed after joining

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @IsDelete INT
DECLARE @external_team_id INT
SELECT  @IsDelete = Count(*) OVER(), @external_team_id = external_team_id from  tbl_service_data  WHERE id = '13481' AND team_type_id = 2

IF @IsDelete = 1
BEGIN
DELETE FROM  tbl_team where  team_id = @external_team_id
END
```